# preserve and pass dynamically generated html table created in javascript to php when submit button is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have to submit a dynamically generated html table that is created using javascript and pass this table to a php mail function when  submit button is clicked  ,I would like to know whether its possible to preserve the dynamically generated table in javascript when the form has any errors also when submit button is clicked and the dynamically generated table is lost . 
I am a beginner and i have fared till making a dynamically generated javascript table with delete  , now i need to pass this table to a php submit button  and then can only proceed further

Any help will be grateful since  time is short for me right now pls help.

the code is as follows

To add rows to a table

```
function addRow(){

var a =document.getElementById("sociallink").value;
    var b =document.getElementById("socialemail").value;
    var c =document.getElementById("socialpass").value;


var media=document.getElementById('media');

if ( media.selectedIndex  ==  "1" )
{
    media_type = "facebook";
}

var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");


var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= media_type;
row.insertCell(2).innerHTML= a;
row.insertCell(3).innerHTML=b;
row.insertCell(3).innerHTML=c;

table.style.display ="block";

}
```

php echoing html is as follows

```
    $form ="<form action='./form3.php'  method='post'  name='seoform'> 
        <tbody id='dataTable' border='1' cellpadding='2'>  
                      <tr>
                  <td> Remove Media </td> 
                      <td> Media </td>
                                <td>Media Link</td>
                                <td> Media Email</td>
                                <td> Media Password </td>

                      </tr>
<tr> 
<td> </td> 
<td  > <input type='submit' name='seoformbtn' value='Register'  />   </td> 
</tr> 


        </tbody> </form> ";

    echo $form;
```

Comment: wrap the generated table in a hidden field and then send it through PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the markup for the table created in an hidden input which is then sent along when the form is submitted.

Add a hidden textarea to your form

```
<textarea id="table-markup"></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
#table-markup{
   display: none;
}
```

give your table an id like so:

`<table id='table'><tbody id='dataTable'>.....</tbody></table>`

```
var tableMarkup = document.getElementById("table");
document.getElementById("table-markup").value = tableMarkup.innerHTML;
```

Now when the form is submitted this will be sent along with it..
I recommend using the POST method to send your form data (depending upon your table markup)

Comment: can u direct me to an example

Comment: I am not understanding how to store generated table in markup , please can u help

Comment: You said that the table is being generated through javascript, right? Then it must be stored in a variable? What i have done is that i have just set the value of textarea to the value of the variable (which contains table markup)

Comment: actually am getting the table from html and inserting the rows using javascript when a add button is clicked

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26704/discussion-between-lucky-soni-and-samantha)

Answer (score 0):

To store the table is simple
lets say your table is

```
<table id='tableid' >......</table>

var tbl = $('#tableid').html();
// to complement previous answer, then you put in hidden field
$("#table-markup").val(tbl);
```